# Extract value in specific range

Tags: python, pandas, replace, extract

I have one dataset with several column:
data-pioggia-name.....

I would like to get values, within of the column pioggia, between 0 and 400.

I tried with:

```
start='0'
end='400'
data = (data['pioggia']>start)&(data['pioggia']<=end)
```

but I have error: `">" not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'`

I tried also:

```
data = data['pioggia'].between(0,400, inclusive=True)
```

but I have the same error.

There is some solution? also for example with replace?

Comment: What is the data type of `data['pioggia']`?

Comment: the type is float64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this line:

```
data['pioggia'] = data['pioggia'].astype(int)
```

Also, make your `start` and `end` variables be ints (e.g. `0`) instead of strings (e.g. `'0'`).

Like this:

```
start = 0 # Notice this and `end` are ints, not strings
end = 400
data['pioggia'] = data['pioggia'].astype(int)

data = (data['pioggia']>start)&(data['pioggia']<=end)
```

Comment: I have other error: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer